# Windows function "GetCursorInfo" returns success but the HANDLE to the cursor is NULL

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to get a `HANDLE` to the global cursor. Therefore I use the Windows function `GetCursorInfo`. The return value of the function is nonzero, which implies that it succeeded. However, the `HANDLE` to the cursor returned is `NULL`.

This is the code I am using:

```
CURSORINFO ci;
ci.cbSize = sizeof(ci);
if (!GetCursorInfo(&ci)) {
    cout << "GetCursorInfo() failed" << endl;
    return 1;
}
cout << ci.hCursor << endl; // ci.hCursor is 0x00000000
```

I am only getting this error on my Intel NUC with Windows 10 (not on a normal PC with Windows 10).

I cannot find this error anywhere else so help would be very appreciated!

Comment: What is the value of the `flags` field when the `hCursor` is NULL?

Comment: The value of `flags` is 0.

Comment: That means "The cursor is hidden"

Comment: this isn't C at all. Why tag C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really "a tablet mode". If you need a cursor shape w/o physical mouse, just call `ShowCursor(TRUE)` beforehand.

Windows user subsystem tracks global cursor visibility by maintaining an internal counter of [`ShowCursor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showcursor) calls which incremented on `ShowCursor(TRUE)` and decremented on `ShowCursor(FALSE)`. This counter really was global in 16-bit Windows and then moved to GUI tread local storage in Win32.
And now: the initial value of this counter is `-1` (hidden) when no pointing device present and `0` (showing) otherwise.
A side note: there is no general way to unobtrusively query this counter value, meaning there is risk of causing cursor to blink.

See also [Raymond Chen's](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091217-00/?p=15643) for more practical example of visual feedback on miceless system.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I have figured out why this is happening:

I am connecting to my Intel NUC remotely and therefore don't have a physical mouse connected. This appears to cause the problem. As soon as I connect a physical mouse everything works as intended again.

Windows seems to be switching to tablet mode once there is no mouse connected and therefore hides the cursor.